# #test div appearing on some images, not others

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The text on this page has a div of test which I can reposition using CSS.

http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/clothing

```
                        <div id="test"><a href="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/product/1980s-stanley-platos-dress">1980&#8242;s Stanley Platos Dress</a></div>          
        <div class="wrapper-price">
                        <div class="entry-price">
            &pound;106.00               </div><!-- entry-price -->

                        <div class="entry-post-thumbnail">
                <a class="tcp_size-medium" href="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/product/1980s-stanley-platos-dress"><img width="200" height="300" src="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/stanley-platos-dress-front-200x300.jpg" class="attachment-medium wp-post-image" alt="stanley-platos-dress-front" title="stanley-platos-dress-front" /></a>
            </div><!-- .entry-post-thumbnail -->
                    </div><!-- .wrapper-price -->

   #tcp_shortcode_all_clothing #test {
        position: relative;
        top: 298px;
    }
```

But the div doesn't seem to appear on other pages so I can't reposition the text:

http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/outerwear

Comment: Double check to make sure they are using the same templates maybe?

Comment: your first problem is that you have multiple elements with the same id (#test) you firstly need to switch that to a class if you want to use it more than once as ID's should eb unique to a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you view source on the page you supplied (http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/outerwear) you will see the element is not actually wrapped in an element with id="test", that is your problem, it seems you are using two different templates for those pages.

Sample from problem page here:

```
<tr class="tcp_first-row">
    <td id="td-post-480" class="tcp_col tcp_4_cols tcp_col_1">
            <div id="post-480" class="post-480 tcp_product type-tcp_product status-publish hentry">
<a href="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/product/vintage-gianfranco-ferre-coat">Vintage Gianfranco Ferre Coat</a>            
            <div class="wrapper-price">
                            <div class="entry-price">
                &pound;180.00               </div><!-- entry-price -->

                            <div class="entry-post-thumbnail">
                    <a class="tcp_size-medium" href="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/product/vintage-gianfranco-ferre-coat"><img width="200" height="300" src="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/gianfranco-coat-front-200x300.jpg" class="attachment-medium wp-post-image" alt="gianfranco-coat-front" title="gianfranco-coat-front" /></a>
                </div><!-- .entry-post-thumbnail -->
                        </div><!-- .wrapper-price -->
```

Versus the working page:

```
<tr class="tcp_first-row">
    <td id="td-post-491" class="tcp_col tcp_4_cols tcp_col_1">
            <div id="post-491" class="post-491 tcp_product type-tcp_product status-publish hentry">


                            <div id="test"><a href="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/product/1980s-stanley-platos-dress">1980&#8242;s Stanley Platos Dress</a></div>          
            <div class="wrapper-price">
                            <div class="entry-price">
                &pound;106.00               </div><!-- entry-price -->

                            <div class="entry-post-thumbnail">
                    <a class="tcp_size-medium" href="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/product/1980s-stanley-platos-dress"><img width="200" height="300" src="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/stanley-platos-dress-front-200x300.jpg" class="attachment-medium wp-post-image" alt="stanley-platos-dress-front" title="stanley-platos-dress-front" /></a>
                </div><!-- .entry-post-thumbnail -->
                        </div><!-- .wrapper-price -->
```

That said as commeneted above, you really need to  switch that `id="test"` to `class="test"` as ID's should be unique to a page.